# How to use display_url as a parameter in twitter api

Tags: php, json, api, twitter

Currently, I am passing name as a parameter and fetching the result like `screen_name`, `location`, `extended_url`, `display_url` .. etc.

My query is like this

```
$tweets = $twitter->get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json?q=ABC');
```

Can you please help me in passing display_url as a parameter and fetch the data from it.
Like

```
$tweets = $twitter->get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json?display_url=abc.com');
```

If I pass my url like this, I am getting error like

```
stdClass Object
(
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [code] => 25
                    [message] => Query parameters are missing.
                )

        )

)
```

Please help me in this.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

`display_url` can't be used in the search API, read here:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets

Why not do a `q=` search on your website?

Comment: Yes, it is not giving results for all the domains. For example.. if i pass q=abc.com i am getting the result. But, it is not working for all types of url's

Comment: For example, I passed one url like $tweets = $twitter->get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json?q=wzes.pasco.k12.fl.us'); which already has a twitter account. But not displaying any results if i pass the url like this. I think Now you undedrstand the problem which I am facing.

Comment: Its correcty you don't get any result. The Twitter website also cant find tweets https://twitter.com/search?q=wzes.pasco.k12.fl.us&src=typd&f=realtime

Comment: Hi @JackPoint, what u shown is right. But, Can you please try to understand the problem which i am facing. https://twitter.com/WZESBulldogs, is the twitter link for the above url which i had given. I dont have the screen_name WZESBulldogs and any other details to fetch the page. I have only url. By using that url, I need to get the twitter screen_name. I think now you got what I am trying to do.. if not, i will explain you clearly.

Comment: Do you wanna search tweets or users? You can search in users with `users/search` and add the `q=` param with the website.

Comment: The similar kind of result, i am getting an empty array Array() as a output. Now, I am using my query like $tweets = $twitter->get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json?q=wzes.pasco.k12.fl.us');

Comment: There are other services like http://www.fullcontact.com/ and http://rapportive.com/ that coul help you find twitter users by website URL. Twitter doesn't allow you to do this.